# Finding IP address

Tags: ip, ethernet, network

I have a device (logger for data acquisition), ut seems that someone has changed it's default IP address and lost it. I can't access it. Is there's a way to find it's IP?

Comment: There are plenty of questions with answers here about this, such as the one linked above.

Comment: I tired Wireshark, but no output, also tried ip scanner with no output